# How to load fragments into SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am butchering the `SlidingTabsBasic` example for my own requirements. I have done very little with tabbed layouts so am unsure what to do next.

I have created 3 tabs using `SlidingTabLayout`. I have a Fragment I want to use for each but I don't know how to load each fragment into the tabs. The example from Google just uses the tab ID to change a text label to match the tab ID.

```
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            // Inflate a new layout from our resources
            View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                    container, false);
            // Add the newly created View to the ViewPager
            container.addView(view);

            // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));



            // Return the View
            return view;
        }
```

Can post all code if necessary but didn't want to overload the post. Also I haven't changed any other code (from the downloaded sample)

**EDIT:**

Here is the code from my adapter, which populates the titles correctly but doesn't seem to get the fragements (just get a white screen with the tabs. Have created `Tab1.java` etc and a layout for each.)

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Tab1();
        case 1:
            return new Tab2();
        case 2:
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
    }
    return 

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position].toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Tabs to work you need to use an adapter setup. I believe the Google code does have an adapter that's created for you to use. 
Essentially, you create a new Java class that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter (depending on your needs), and then set the getItem method to return the fragment you require for each tab.
Here's an example that may help you accomplish your goal:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            FirstFragment fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
            return fragment1;
        case 1:
            SecondFragment fragment2 = new SecondFragment();
            return fragment2;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

The code above lets you select which fragments you require on each tab. Let me know if you need more help

EDIT: Also, a better method for tab names would be to override getPageTitle in the adapter class and return the string titles you want.

Comment: OK so I am getting there now - I have modified the adapter and a new class extending the adapter. `getPageTitle` works but `getItem` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer is that the code fragment you show needs to be inside an adapter. The underlying mechanism is a ViewPager, which, when attached to an adapter, will call this method on each item as its presence is required. I have not looked at their example but its going to orchestrate the calling forth and disposal of each 'page.'